# Object issues in Java

Tags: java, swing, events, graphics, awt

I'm attempting to implement the dragging functionality of shapes on a canvas.  My `Shape` class inherits from `JPanel`.

Absolutely nothing happens when I click on a shape, drag it and let go of the mouse button.  It just remains where it was originally. Any ideas?

Comment: Check out [ComponentMover](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) by @camickr.

Comment: Is the code in getSelectedShape() getting you the correct shape object on mouse clicks?

Comment: Yes indeed, I've tested it and it works. @sampson-chen

Comment: Thanks for the links, however I have written the above code based on such examples and am not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: Where do you update shape.xPosition and shape.yPosition? It seems as a call to getLocation() would be better. And also, have you set a layout manager? I guess that could cause issues as well.

Comment: @TobiasRitzau I don't have any layout managers

Comment: Did you remember to attach a mouse listener to each shape pane??

Comment: Yes, the mouse events all enter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a few basic things:

1. A field for the shape itself (you already had)
2. Fields to keep track of the offset of the click within the shape (already had)
3. A field to keep track of if you're dragging
4. Overwrite the `paintComponent` method to paint your shape
5. A `MouseListener` and `MouseMotionListener` added to the Panel (`MouseAdapter` does both of these)

Here's a basic working example.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawTest extends JPanel{

    //Shape doesn't have a location field - you'd have to keep track of  
    //this yourself if you're set on using the shape interface
    private Rectangle shape = new Rectangle(100, 100);
    // The location within the shape you clicked
    private int xOffset = 0; 
    private int yOffset = 0;
    // To indicate dragging is happening
    boolean isDragging = false;

    public DrawTest(){
        MouseAdapter listener = new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                // Starts dragging and calculates offset
                if(shape.contains(e.getPoint())){
                    isDragging = true;
                    xOffset = e.getPoint().x - shape.x;
                    yOffset = e.getPoint().y - shape.y;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                // Ends dragging
                isDragging = false;
            }


            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                // Moves the shape - doesn't actually need to be a method
                // but is because you had it as one
                if(isDragging){
                    moveShape(e);
                }
            }

            private void moveShape(MouseEvent e) {
                Point newLocation = e.getPoint();
                newLocation.x -= xOffset;
                newLocation.y -= yOffset;
                shape.setLocation(newLocation);
                repaint();
            }
        };

        //Add a mouse mostion listener (for dragging) and regular listener (for clicking)
        addMouseListener(listener);
        addMouseMotionListener(listener);
    }

    // So we have a play area to work with
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(400,300);
    }

    //Paints the shape
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.clearRect(0,0,getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.fillRect(shape.x, shape.y, shape.width, shape.height);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new DrawTest());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: +1 great example ( I lost my own example when my HDD died :0)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp That's about the worst way to lose anything - You have my condolences... (a moment of silence for the deceased)

Comment: @DotNET if you can update your example to a small runnable example, we may be able to point out your mistake.  From the code you have posted, the most likely places where your problem may be happening in points 3, 4 or 5

Comment: I'm surprised, I expect setLayout( null ) to do absolute positioning.

Answer (score 3):

Tried a small simple example

Dragging the rectangle will make it move with the cursor it also checks the bounds so the rectangle cannot be dragged off screen:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ShapeMover {

    public ShapeMover() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Shape Mover");
        initComponents(frame);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ShapeMover();
            }
        });

    }

    private void initComponents(JFrame frame) {
        frame.getContentPane().add(new DragPanel());
    }
}

class DragPanel extends JPanel {

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 50);
    int preX, preY;
    boolean isFirstTime = true;
    Rectangle area;
    boolean pressOut = false;
    private Dimension dim = new Dimension(400, 300);

    public DragPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.white);
        addMouseMotionListener(new MyMouseAdapter());
        addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return dim;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        if (isFirstTime) {
            area = new Rectangle(dim);
            rect.setLocation(50, 50);
            isFirstTime = false;
        }

        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.fill(rect);
    }

    boolean checkRect() {
        if (area == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (area.contains(rect.x, rect.y, 100, 50)) {
            return true;
        }
        int new_x = rect.x;
        int new_y = rect.y;

        if ((rect.x + 100) > area.getWidth()) {
            new_x = (int) area.getWidth() - 99;
        }
        if (rect.x < 0) {
            new_x = -1;
        }
        if ((rect.y + 50) > area.getHeight()) {
            new_y = (int) area.getHeight() - 49;
        }
        if (rect.y < 0) {
            new_y = -1;
        }
        rect.setLocation(new_x, new_y);
        return false;
    }

    private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            preX = rect.x - e.getX();
            preY = rect.y - e.getY();

            if (rect.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                updateLocation(e);
            } else {
                pressOut = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (!pressOut) {
                updateLocation(e);
            } else {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (rect.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                updateLocation(e);
            } else {
                pressOut = false;
            }
        }

        public void updateLocation(MouseEvent e) {
            rect.setLocation(preX + e.getX(), preY + e.getY());
            checkRect();

            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

**Reference:**

- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Event/MoveShapewithmouse.htm